# D3: Update Graph with new data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have implemented this graph d3. The data for constructing the graph are taken from the asynchronous method SpecificMuseum (name).

```
 specificoMuseo(name).then(proof => {

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
        margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right - 150, // sommo 150 perchè la width prima era 1200, mentre ora è stata settata a 1350, in modo da far vedere l'etichetta dei valori correnti, quindi sommo 150 per tenere invece la width (inteso come valore) uguale a prima
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,  // l'altezza del piano grafico
        height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y")
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;;

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
        xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
        yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
        .on("brush end", brushed);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var area = d3.area()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

    var area2 = d3.area()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
        .y0(height2)
        .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var g = svg.append("g")  // riferito al primo piano
    //.attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g") // riferito al secondo piano
        .attr("class", "context")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");



        var data = proof;


        var datax = [{date: 'Jan 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Feb 2007', price:0},{date: 'Mar 2007', price:0}, {date: 'Apr 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'May 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Jun 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Jul 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Aug 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Sep 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Oct 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Nov 2007', price: 0}, {date: 'Dec 2007', price: 0}];

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.price = d.price;
        });

        datax.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.price = d.price;
        });



    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, Math.max(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; }), d3.max(datax, function(d) { return d.price; })) ]);

    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area);

    g.append("path")
        .datum(datax)
        .attr("class", "areax")
        .attr("d", area);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);


    var focus = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("y1", 0)  // punto di inizio della linea
        .attr("y2", height); // punto di fine della linea, dicendomi quanto deve essere lunga

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 0);

    focus.append("text")
        .attr("x", 15)   // mi dice la distanza dall'asse verticale
        .attr("dy", ".31em");

    context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area2);

    context.append("path")
        .datum(datax)
        .attr("class", "areax")
        .attr("d", area2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, x.range());

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("class", "zoom")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zoom)
        // .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);


    });
```

I have implemented this search/filter dropdown:

```
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>
<div class="dropdown">
   <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have the global variable name, which every time I click on one of the values of Search/Filter Dropdown the name takes that value, ie if I click on ACQUARIO then name will be ACQUARIO. When I click on one of the values of Search/Filter Dropdown for example ACQUARIO, I want update the graph with new data, that is specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO")

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item) {  // ITERAZIONE
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a onclick="fnclick(this)">' + item + '</a>';
        })
    });

    var name = "TuttiMusei"; //global variable so you can access in your method
    var data;


    function fnclick(obj) {
        name = obj.innerHTML;        
    }


    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    function filterFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
        a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                a[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                a[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    function allNameMuseums() {
        return ["ACQUARIO", "TuttiMusei"];
    }
```

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8 <-- updating data on a d3js graph on click.

Comment: I have seen, but I have the asyn method specificoMuseo(name) that returns data to build graph. How I do?

Comment: If I add the method updateData() outside the promise, there will be undefined  variables because the entire code of graph is inside the promise

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with some sample data real quick? It'd be easier to edit the same.